# Running an hta above all windows

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I have an HTML application that I want to stay on top of all windows (that is, if another window is opened/switched to, I want this one to cover it).  JavaScript solutions don't work in Windows 7/IE9 Mode (not sure which is holding it back, can't change either), and VBScript solutions seem to either fail outright or depend on outside components.  I can't use modal dialogs either because I need this to be on top of ALL other windows, not just its parent.

And don't mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539339/how-to-open-a-hta-window-on-top-of-all-other-windows because that (unfortunately still unanswered) question refers to opening above other windows, not maintaining stack position.

What I have tried:

- Three of the suggestions outlined [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/d1948ca9-5066-481b-822f-145664890437/hta-always-on-top).
- The JavaScript solution [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Always-On-Top-m70146.aspx).
- The little VBScript [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/HTA-above-other-windows-m67113.aspx).
- Probably a dozen or more subtle variations on each of the above.

Keep in mind that I can't download an extra component (no autoit or nircmd).  It should all be integrated into a single file, preferably an hta, but not a zip.

### My Solution

Only very slightly adapted from Teemu's solution, mainly for portability (just in case).

```
<script language="javascript">
    var locationstore = location.href
    [...]
    window.onload = function () {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'),
            forceModal = function (e) {
                shell.Run(locationstore, 1, 0);
            };
        top.addEventListener('blur', forceModal, false);
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            window.removeEventListener('blur', forceModal, false);
        };
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an evil snippet. It's not perfect, but maybe you can develope it further.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'),
        forceModal = function (e) {
            shell.Run('absolute_path_to_hta', 1, 0);
        };
    top.addEventListener('blur', forceModal, false);
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.removeEventListener('blur', forceModal, false);
    };
};
```

WARNING: HTA must run in single instance mode, when testing this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/vbscript'> 

window.setInterval "SetToFocus()", 100

        Function SetToFocus()
        window.focus()
        set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
        objShell.MinimizeAll
        End Function

</script>
```

This baby will hide any other windows and make itself on top.

Comment: MinimizeAll minimized itself as well and when it minimizes itself, it wants to be on top, so it minimizes everything and so on...

Comment: Just add `WINDOWSTATE="maximize"` on the `HTA: application` and you're good

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type=text/vbscript">
    set objAPP=createobject("Shell.application") 
    Do
    wscript.sleep 500
    objAPP.AppActivate"Your Window Name"
    Loop
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: An infinite loop like that is going to waste a lot of CPU cycles. Add a `wscript.sleep 500` between the `Do` and the `Loop` to keep it's impact minimal.