# Push window to front with hidden powershell

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, vbscript, hta

I have a scheduled task that starts a hidden-window PowerShell script. The script does some stuff, starts an HTA and waits for the HTA to close:

```
Start-Process $HTApath -Wait
```

and then the PoSh script does some other stuff.  Everything works great on many machines (Win7 & 10), but other (fairly stock) systems, the HTA often doesn't come to the front and is not seen for hours/days.  That's a problem.

I have included javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
[...]
window.focus();
```

**AND** vbscript:

```
<script language='vbscript'>
Sub window_toFront
  Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Shell.AppActivate("UAlbany Security Updates Policy Reboot Notice")
End Sub
window_toFront
```

in the HTA, and I've put in timed loops to repeat the attempts.  On the machines where the window comes to the front initially, the loops do a very nice job forcing the window back to the front, but on the machines that ignore the directive, repeating the attempt does nothing.  Those machines are running the other VBS/JS scripts in the HTA; It is *ONLY* the push-to-front commands that are not working.

I also tried [this "evil" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793911/running-an-hta-above-all-windows).  It also failed to work on some machines (and crashed a VM).

I've tried testing PoSh options that could be used externally to the HTA (i.e. replacing the Start-Process call in the scheduled script):

```
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@

$PID = [diagnostics.process]::start("HTApath").id
start-sleep -Seconds 1
$Handle = (Get-Process -Id $PID).MainWindowHandle

While ((Get-Process -Id $PID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null) {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   [void] [Tricks]::SetForegroundWindow($Handle)
}
```

but it only seems to work if the PoSh window is made active (which won't happen for this process).

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting this to work?  I'm particularly interested in understanding why the internal-HTA methods are so hit-or-miss; Is there a Windows/IE setting that could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: By design, Windows doesn't let applications mess with the focus willy-nilly.  However, this was retrofitted in and so has a lot of heuristics for backwards compatibility, making it a little unpredictable.  If I remember correctly, setting `SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT` to zero turns all of this off.  Assuming this is for in-house use, or on an embedded system or something, that would probably solve your problem.  You would have to do it from an application that runs automatically when the user logs in, e.g., using the Startup folder in the Start Menu.

Comment: This is an in-house application.  I understand the problem with this approach as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).  There should be a way for the domain admins to approve specific apps/processes as "more special".  That would protect against crap-ware while allowing truly important stuff to push forward.  The SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT looks like the most likely workable solution, I just need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm looking into adding balloon tips.  If I have the BalloonClicked_Event set to (re)open the HTA, will that bring it to the front?  I'm guessing it would behave like an application started by the user double-clicking the icon.

Comment: I expect that would work, but I've never tried it.

Comment: ... incidentally, when replying to someone on Stack Overflow it is best to ping them by including an @ sign followed by their username.  That way they get notified of your response.  So @HarryJohnston for example.  Note that you can only specify *one* such user per comment.

Comment: [Assistive Technology applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx) get some special privileges, but I'm not sure offhand whether that includes the ability to force another application into the foreground.  (It does say "an assistive technology application with UIAccess can run as the topmost application in the z-order at any time".)  Might be worth investigating if changing the lock timeout doesn't pan out.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, in order to use UIAccess, an application needs to be signed, trusted and have a manifest, so I won't be able to do that for quite some time (when I get a bigger brain).