# Browseforfolder window stays underneath

Tags: vbscript, wincc

I work with Siemens WinCC and it offers the possibility to run simple VBS code.
I have managed to open a folder selection window through "BrowseForFolder" but this window is below the SCADA that executes it, which is also executed full screen and should not allow the user going to the desktop (so, go to there and press the folder selection window icon is not an option). Any way to open this window always on top?.

Thankyou for your help.

```
Dim oFolder, BrowseForFolder
On Error Resume Next 

Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0,MsjInfo,0,0)
     
  If (oFolder Is Nothing) Then
    BrowseForFolder = Empty
  Else 
    BrowseForFolder = oFolder.Self.Path
  End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an hta above all windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795744)

Comment: You are not specifying an hWnd, the first parameter. Pass in the hWnd of the containing app.

Comment: *Dialog boxes and message boxes are owned windows by default. An application specifies the owner window when calling a function that creates a dialog box or message box.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows

Comment: @user692942 Your link has nothing to do with this question. The questioner is NOT passing an hwnd to browseforfolder. In Windows dialogs are owned by the main windows. Therefore to work as expected you must pass the hwnd in. Passing an hwnd of 0 means the desktop is the owner. That means the window is treated the same as any application eg notepad.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll see if your information helps with my problem!.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Note

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Note